# Irreducible representations over $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

How to prove that all irreducible representations over $\mathbb{R}$ of finite abelian group have dimension 1 or 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all elements $g$ in your finite abelian group $G$, you have an endomorphism on your vector space $V$ underlying your representation. Since your group is abelian, these endomorphisms commute, hence you can diagonalize them *simultaneously* (over $\mathbb C$). This proves, of course, that over the complex numbers (or any algebraically closed field), your irreducible representations are one-dimensional.

Over $\mathbb R$, the best you can hope for is that your endomorphisms can be block-diagonalized simultaneously, with blocks of size at most 2. This is because an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb R$ has degree at most 2. EDIT: Let's prove this. If your polynomial has odd degree, then it has a root (this is a consequence of the intermediate value theorem). Now, suppose your polynomial has even degree. By looking at its solutions over $\mathbb C$, we know they come in conjugate pairs $z$, $\overline z$. Therefore, both $(X-z)$ and $(X-\overline z)$ divide your polynomial, and therefore, so does their product, which is a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients. Therefore, any real polynomial of degree at least 3 is *reducible*.

Therefore, your irreducible representations are at most two-dimensional.

Comment: What you think about this proof?

We have a set of commutative operators, so
they have common eigenvector z over \mathbb{C}.

Represent z = x+iy where x and y real vectors.

<x,y> invariant two dimensional subspace so representation is reducible

Comment: @vasa There is no way to know that the (real) subspace spanned by $x$ and $y$ is invariant under $G$.

Comment: Bad. I don't understand why Over R, the best you can hope for is that your endomorphisms can be block-diagonalized simultaneously, with blocks of size at most 2 (this is because an irreducible polynomial over R has degree at most 2)

Comment: @vasa I added a proof of this statement.

Comment: How about this?

 $z = x + iy. A(x+iy) =(a+bi)(x+iy) = (ax-by)+i(bx+ay). A(x-iy)=(a-ib)(x-iy)$. Vectors $x+iy, x-iy$ are independent because they correspond distinct eigenvalues. Lets prove that $x, y$ are independent. $a x+b y=0. (a-ib)(x+iy)+(a+ib)(x-iy)=2(ax+by)=0.$ Therefore $a+ib = a-ib =0$ and $a=b=0$ so vectors $x, y$ are independent and $<x,y>$ invariant subspace.

Comment: @vasa: You can turn that idea into a complete proof as follows. The commutative set of operators has matrices (w.r.t. the original basis) with real coefficient. Therefore if $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$ is a common complex eigenvector, then so is the componentwise conjugate $\overline{z}$. The span $L$ of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ is closed under componentwise conjugation. Therefor $L$ intersects the original real vector space in a subspace of dimension $2$. And that will also be stable under the action of the group.

Comment: The passage from real to complex and back to real space follows similar lines as in [this answer by yours truly](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/68588/11619). There the situation is a bit different, but the technique is the same.

Comment: Full proof looks like :
Let assume that we have irreducible representation over \mathbb{R} with dimension more than 2. As i wrote upper than we have 1 or 2 dimensional invariant subspace and contradiction with irreducibility.
Any errors?

Comment: @vasa This is fine

Comment: thanks guys. How to gave reputation to you?