# The Determinant of a Transition Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

Suppose we have a linear map $T$ whose matrix is $A$ such that $$A: V \rightarrow V$$ where $A$ is the transition matrix from the basis $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ to the basis $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$.

If the determinant of $A$ is positive, then the orientation of the basis $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ if the same as $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$. If negative, then they have opposite orientations.

Can someone explain why this is? Why are two bases oriented the same if the transition matrix has a positive determinant? What does it mean for two bases to be of the same orientation?

Comment: Can you give the definition of orientation you are using? This might help both us and you to see a solution for your problem.

Comment: Say the standard basis $(i,j,k)$ is positively oriented because of the right hand rule where k is the thumb, fingers curling from i to j. Sorry, I'm not really too sure, I hope this is what you are looking for to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the definition of ‘same orientation’ and ‘opposite orientation’. To change basis between two bases of same orientation (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), you need to perform a rotation (i.e. orthogonal matrix) and a scaling/shearing (i.e. positive-definite matrix).
If, however, you want to change between two bases of different orientations, you have to perform a reflexion as well. Think of it like this: every basis that is oriented differently is just a basis oriented equally with two swapped basis vectors, just as every invertible matrix of negative determinant is just an invertible matrix of positive determinant with two rows swapped

Answer (score 1):

Think you are rotating the coordinate system. $A\in \mathbb{SO}(d)$, so the determinant is 1. If the scaling is also there then the determinant is positive but may not be 1.

On the other hand, you require a reflection, that is why the determinant is negative.

Comment: This might be silly, but why does a transformation that is a reflection give a negative determinant?

Comment: If you want to learn more about this, then you have to study yourself. For your convenience, check this one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68119/why-does-ata-i-det-a-1-mean-a-is-a-rotation-matrix

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look